# Can't rewrite URL because parameters are dynamic

Tags: php, regex, url, nginx

I'm making an API, everything is handled inside the file, so here's what an example URL might look like.

```
https://website.com/api/?type=search&user=bob
```

And I'd want that to turn into

```
https://website.com/api/search/bob
```

But now here's the other part to this issue. I have another `type`, which is CSRF

```
https://website.com/api/?type=csrf
```

And that would be

```
https://website.com/api/csrf/
```

Note that it's one parameter short, but yet still working off the same file. Anything i've tried never seems to work correctly. Additionally there always seems to be a `\` added to the `api` file. I've already removed the `.php` from there.

So when I try this it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /api/?type=$1&user=$2;
```

Comment: I've always found it a million times easier to just route all urls through a php script and then use php to parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to include other pages. Else you end up having to write a hundred rewrite rules and they seem to get in the way more than they need to.

Comment: Right after I posted this I started looking into `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Now I'm just stuck on parsing that `URI`. Any good posts on here that show that part? @JonathanKuhn

Comment: There are plenty of pre-made routers out there (maps urls to include files) or you can make your own simply as `explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` and then just make up your own fixed structure like if key `[0]` is `api` then key `[1]` tells you what page to include and any other keys are handled in that included page. Then the included page just needs to look for key `[2]` for the username or whatever. It's not hard and you can do it pretty easy.

Comment: Alright, so far so good. Bt the only issue is when I do `api/search/bob` I get a 404. Is there any way I can "prevent" that from happening and allow anything after the `api` part? @JonathanKuhn

Comment: I just like to rewrite everything through a single script. For your case, I would just map anything that goes through `/api/` to a single script. So a rule like `RewriteRule ^api/.* api.php` would route everything that goes to `/api/` to a single `api.php` file (which can be any file you want). Then just explode on the slash in api.php and parse from there. It will make everything much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you use `$2` for your username and this correspond to `([0-9]+)` in your regular expression.

Which means, username will have to be numbers only.

Change your expression to :

```
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)$ /api/?type=$1&user=$2;
```

And your rules should work.